# How to retrieve the list of all installed keyboards in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I am trying to write a simple function that will check to see if a specific keyboard is installed.

Here is what I have in the function so far:

```
func isCustomKeyboardEnabled() {

    let bundleID:NSString = "com.company.MyApp.Keyboard"

    let installedKeyboards = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("AppleKeyboards")

    println(installedKeyboards)

}
```

This is what it returns in the console:

```
Optional((
    "en_GB@hw=British;sw=QWERTY",
    "emoji@sw=Emoji",
    "com.nuance.swype.app.Global-Keyboard",
))
```

I am having an hard time checking to see if my `bundleID` is in this returned object. I've tried a `for in` and an`if(contains(x,x))` but it fails to build. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 2.0 Solution:**

```
func installedKeyboards(){
    if let installedKeyboard = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("AppleKeyboards") as? [String]{
        if installedKeyboard.contains("Your Unique Identifier"){
            print("Custom Keyboard Found")
        }else{
            print("Custom Keyboard Not Installed")
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: hi @Statik, how to select specific keyboard from list of applekeyboard programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an `Optional` response there, meaning that the value could be `nil`. Try doing this instead:

```
if let installedKeyboards = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("AppleKeyboards") {
  if (contains(installedKeyboards, "Your keyboard") {
    // Do stuff.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I have tried this and I get this error: `Generic parameter 'S' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swift 4 version from Statik answer:

```
func installedKeyboards() {
    if let installedKeyboard = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleKeyboards") as? [String] {
        if installedKeyboard.contains("Your Unique Identifier") {
            print("Custom Keyboard Found")
        }
        else {
            print("Custom Keyboard Not Installed")
        }
    }
}
```